# Изменение даты в ссылке angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Можно ли сделать чтобы в ссылке динамически менялась дата?

Например сегодня 11.10.2016 и нужно ввести дату в ссылку

как например тут:
**`start=20161011&finish20161011`**

Ну и также идентично для для недели месяца и года

```html
var CupApp = angular.module('CupApp', []);
  CupApp.controller('CupCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http://buff:123@192.168.0.7:8080/pt/hs/buffnew/total?start=20160101&finish=20161231').success(function(data) {
      $scope.cups = data;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Не имеется решений этого вопроса?

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date(),
year = date.getFullYear(),
month = date.getMonth(),
day = date.getDate(),
fullDate = '' + year + (month + 1) + day;
$http.get('http://buff:123@192.168.0.7:8080/pt/hs/buffnew/total?start=' + fullDate + '&finish=' + fullDate).success(function(data) {
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Не работает к сожалению =(

Comment: @heymukki, может проблема была не в клиенте, а в том как сервер обрабатывал данный запрос? и действительно для таких значений возвращал 404 ошибку?